# ODBCConfig.exe failing during ConfigSysDSN with a Teradata Driver

Tags: windows, odbc, teradata, dsn

My company is rolling out a new software that, in order to be used as intended, requires access to our Teradata DB. In order to simplify this rollout for the people that will be installing it, I am trying to write a program, currently in python, that creates a DSN with the appropriate driver and parameters. Currently, my python program extracts the username from windows, asks the user for their password, then injects those into a string which is passed to the console with `os.system` in order to make the DSN. The statement ends up looking like

```
ODBCCONF /A {CONFIGSYSDSN "Teradata" "DSN=TestTest|DBCName=edtdpcop2.host.name|UID=user|PWD=pass"}
```

but, for simplicity's sake, I've tried cutting the parameters down to `"DSN=TestTest|DBCName=edtdpcop2.host.name"`

I tried running this from the python program, initially, but the Driver Configuration Program kept stopping. So I tried running the same line directly from `cmd`, but had exactly the same results. I'm using the syntax provided by the [ODBCConfig.exe documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/odbcconf-exe) and the parameter names from my Teradata drivers user guide.[image]

Clicking Debug and running it through Visual Studio 2017 yields:
[image]

I'm running this on Windows 7 Enterprise with a Teradata Driver version 15.10.

#### Update 1:

I remembered this morning that I downloaded the 16.00 driver from the Teradata website, which did not replace the company-pushed 15.10 driver, but installed with a different name, instead. I tried this again with the 16.00 driver and it worked fine. To double check that this was the issue, I tried it on a co-worker's computer which only had the company-pushed 15.10 driver and it failed again.

While this doesn't really solve my overall problem of creating an executable to setup a DSN on the rest of my coworker's computers with minimal effort, it does at least point to the driver as the issue; which still moves me forward toward my goal.

Comment: I'm no expert here, but this feels very much like a ODBCConf.exe issue. Your syntax for the command looks right and the settings to make a connection to Teradata look good as well. Are you able to make this DSN manually in odbc administrator?

Comment: Yea. I don't have any issues making one manually. I'm going to test it out on a co-worker's computer tomorrow to see if the issue is somehow specific to my machine.

Comment: You can also downgrade to 14.10 as another option.

Comment: The IT department here controls versions and pushes updates as they get them. They do have a 14.10 driver available, but only in 32 bit and the application we're implementing requires 64.